# Elegant way to assign value only when it is not None

Tags: python

This is my current implementation:

```
def update_obj(obj_id, field1=None, field2=None):
    obj = ... # some code to get object by obj_id
    if field1 is not None:
        obj.field1 = field1   
    if field2 is not None:
        obj.field2 = field2

update_obj(1, field1='new value')
update_obj(2, field2='new value')
update_obj(3, field1='new value', field2='another new value')
```

I try do the evaluation in one line, like:

```
obj.field1 = field1 if field1 is not None else ob.field1
```

However, the `obj.field1 = obj.field1` is quite redundant and `obj.field1 = field1 if field1 is not None` is not a valid statement.
Any suggestion to make it simpler and cleaner? I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: I think your current code is perfectly idiomatic and you should keep it like it is.

Comment: I'm afraid , you're using the best method

Comment: if it happens a lot maybe consider writing a func `set_if_None`

Comment: Consider changing the design. Making dozens of arguments that duplicate each field is rather awkward [and thus considered poor design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443527/python-decorator-to-automatically-define-init-variables/28444093#28444093). Maybe accepting a `dict` and/or using `__setitem__`. Structuring the set of args and splitting the "god object" into multiple ones accordingly as suggested on the link may also be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If it's code duplication that bothers you, you may use reflection, e.g.:

```
obj.__dict__.update(n,v for n,v in locals() if n in 'field1','field2' and v is not None)
```

Comment: This is cool line! But it might not be that easy to read and maintain as the number of my fields of object is actually quite a lot. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `or`.

```
obj.field1 = field1 or or obj.field1
```

It doesn't remove the redundancy, but it is a little more concise.

Comment: It doesn't work when `field1` has a value that evaluates to boolean false, such as `0`, `[]`, etc.

Comment: Absolutely, if you want this to work for "False" values, then the OP's original code is probably what I'd use.